# regex: To not allow user enter repetitive number formed using 0 and 9

Tags: regex

I want to create regex that can prevent entry of numbers `0000 0000` or `99999 99999` formed using 0 and 9, space can appear anywhere in the formed numbers.

I have tried my hands on [this](https://regex101.com/r/i2TWrE/2/) and it is working 80% accurately. Though it also allows number formed using the combination of 0 and 9 eg. 0000 9999

For this issue I need guidance to prevent this combined input of 0 and 9.

Update:
I am trying to prevent standalone numbers created using either a `0` or `9` in other words `999999999` `9999 9999` `9999999 9` `9 9999999` and `000000000` `0000 0000` `0000000 0` `0 0000000` are unacceptable input.

However, `909090909` `009 00990` `000 99999` `999900000` `123456879` `555228899` etc. are acceptable input.

Thanks

Comment: The requirements you have stated can literally be met by rejecting all possible input.

Comment: You need to clarify your requirements. What exactly constitutes a value that  should be rejected (or accepted)?

Comment: @Kaz we can't determine the place of a single space in first place. second thing 0 and 9 should be part of other combination as well, that you will get using 0-9.

Comment: @Nick I have update the question with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex which had negative lookaheads for a string that was comprised of all zeros and spaces or all nines and spaces, and then match on a string of digits and spaces i.e.

```
^(?![0 ]+$)(?![9 ]+$)([\d ]+)$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/i2TWrE/3/)

If you want to enforce that there can only be one space in the number, add a positive lookahead for that:

```
^(?![0 ]+$)(?![9 ]+$)(?=[^ ]* ?[^ ]*$)([\d ]+)$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/i2TWrE/4/)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that maybe these two positive lookahead statements (checking for both 0 and 9) might be somewhat helpful to solve the problem:

```
(?=.*0)(?=.*9)
```

based on which we can for instance write some simple expression such as:

```
(?=.*0)(?=.*9)^[09]+\s?[09]+$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/fzdLo6/1/)

---

If you'd wanted to allow these samples,

```
123456879
555228899
```

without zeros or nines, then maybe an alternation

```
(?=.*0)(?=.*9)^[09]+\s?[09]+$|(?=.*[0-8])(?=.*[1-9])^[0-9]+\s?[0-9]+$
```

would be an option.

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/2DIlhc/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UDNDvn/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/UDNDvn/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: I was looking for this `RegEx Circuit` thing a while ago. Thanks for including it here.